# mapping two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays A and B.

```
A = np.array ([[ 1  3] [ 2  3]  [ 2  1] ])

B = np.array([(1, 'Alpha'), (2, 'Beta'), (3, 'Gamma')]
```

How can I map A with B in order to get something like:

```
result = np.array ([[ 'Alpha'  'Gamma'] [ 'Beta'  'Gamma']  ['Beta'  'Alpha'] ])
```

I have tried `map(B['f1'],A)` but I am getting `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray'  object is not callable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `NumPythonic` vectorized approach -

```
B[:,1][(A == B[:,0].astype(int)[:,None,None]).argmax(0)]
```

Sample run on a generic case -

```
In [118]: A
Out[118]: 
array([[4, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 4]])

In [119]: B
Out[119]: 
array([['3', 'Alpha'],
       ['4', 'Beta'],
       ['2', 'Gamma']], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [120]: B[:,1][(A == B[:,0].astype(int)[:,None,None]).argmax(0)]
Out[120]: 
array([['Beta', 'Alpha'],
       ['Gamma', 'Alpha'],
       ['Gamma', 'Beta']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary and a list comprehension :

```
>>> d=dict(B)
>>> np.array([[(d[str(i)]),d[str(j)]] for i,j in A])
array([['Alpha', 'Gamma'],
       ['Beta', 'Gamma'],
       ['Beta', 'Alpha']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using any specific numpy things you could do:

```
d = dict(B)
[[d.get(str(y)) for y in x] for x in A]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want a numpy solution for efficiency. In this case, try to
give your association table a more "numpythonic" appearance :

```
A = np.array ([[ 1,  3], [ 2,  3] , [ 2,  1] ])
B = np.array([(0,'before'),(1, 'Alpha'), (2, 'Beta'), (3, 'Gamma')])
C=np.array([b[1] for b in B])
```

Then the result is just : `C.take(A)`.